# In which view controller delegate method do i request the api.?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have been developing a weather application in iOS 8 . I need to display the parsed JSON when the view displays. I am not sure in which delegate methods do i need to request the api. i know it should be requested in the background thread. which are the delegate methods run on background thread?

Answer (score 0):

you can call your api in every where!
for example call in : **AppDelegate** or in **initialize viewController**.

but remember :  your request is **async** so if the request going to fail or getting timed out you should handle it or notify toy first View Controller.

Comment: @Mohamed Thanks i appreciate that.